# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset since TLSv1.2 protocol

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm no more able to connect to api.softlayer.com
I'm calling the rest API from a WebSphere application portal 8.5 (java7) using Apache (HTTP-client-4.5.3.jar)

The coding is

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

The error is

```
17:44:00.997 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://api.softlayer.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
17:44:01.044 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://api.softlayer.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
17:44:01.044 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://api.softlayer.com:443
17:44:01.060 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to api.softlayer.com/66.228.119.120:443
17:44:01.060 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to api.softlayer.com/66.228.119.120:443 with timeout 0
17:44:01.606 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1]
17:44:01.606 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
17:44:01.606 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
17:44:01.747 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
17:44:01.747 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
17:44:01.747 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://api.softlayer.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
17:44:01.747 [main] INFO  o.a.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://api.softlayer.com:443: Connection reset
17:44:01.747 [main] DEBUG o.a.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:207) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:133) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:110) ~[na:7.0 build_20131216]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:141) ~[na:7.0 build_20131216]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:691) ~[na:7.0 build_20131216]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:266) ~[na:7.0 build_20131216]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:770) ~[na:7.0 build_20131216]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.startHandshake(qc.java:476) ~[na:7.0 build_20131216]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
```

**The solution is to enable the enable TLSv1.2**

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;

public class HttpClientFactory {
    private static CloseableHttpClient client;
    public static HttpClient getHttpsClient() throws Exception {
        if (client != null) {
            return client;
        }
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.createDefault();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new String[] { "TLSv1.2"}, null, new NoopHostnameVerifier());
        client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
        return client;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Softlayer's servers only accept TLSv1.2 connections you must make sure that your code is only performing connections with that protocol which it seems your code is not doing

> 17:44:01.606 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -
>   Enabled protocols: [TLSv1]